# Java sorting list of array vs sorting list of list

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator

I have a **list of points** where each **point** is a tiny **list** of size `2`. I want to sort the list of points in increasing order of `x` and if `x` values are equal, I break tie by sorting in decreasing order of `y`.

I wrote a custom comparator to sort the points like this:

```
Collections.sort(points, (a, b) -> {
    if (a.get(0) != b.get(0)) {
        return a.get(0) - b.get(0);
    } return b.get(1) - a.get(1); 
});
```

Here's the **input** before sorting:

```
(2, 1000)
(9, -1000)
(3, 15)
(9, -15)
(5, 12)
(12, -12)
(5, 10)
(10001, -10)
(19, 8)
(10001, -8)
```

Here's the **result** produced after sorting with the above comparator:

```
(2, 1000)
(3, 15)
(5, 12)
(5, 10)
(9, -15)
(9, -1000)
(12, -12)
(19, 8)
(10001, -10)
(10001, -8)
```

**Observations:**

1. The input is sorted in ascending order on `x`.
2. `(5, 12)` was correctly put before `(5, 10)`.
3. `(9, -15)` was correctly put before `(9, -1000)`.
4. However, `(10001, -10)` was put before `(10001, -8)`. Even though `-8` is larger than `-10`.

Feel like I am missing something trivial. I experimented with a few other ways of writing the comparator like using `Integer.compare(a, b)` or just `a.compareTo(t)`, but got the same result.

Finally, I changed the representation of point from `List<Integer>` to `int[]` and wrote the same comparator again. See results below:

```
Collections.sort(points, (a, b) -> {
    if (a[0] != b[0])
        return a[0] - b[0];
    return b[1] - a[1];
});
```

**Input** before sorting:

```
(2, 1000)
(9, -1000)
(3, 15)
(9, -150
(5, 12)
(12, -12)
(5, 10)
(10001, -10)
(19, 8)
(10001, -8)
```

**After sorting:**

```
(2, 1000)
(3, 15)
(5, 12)
(5, 10)
(9, -15)
(9, -1000)
(12, -12)
(19, 8)
(10001, -8)
(10001, -10)
```

So list of arrays is getting sorted correctly as `(10001, -8)` was correctly put before `(10001, -10)`.

I am not able to understand why changing the representation of point resolved the issue and hence this question. I can give more details on how I am creating the List of points if required.

Comment: `I am missing something trivial` - That's true. Don't compare objects like that `!a.get(0) != b.get(0)`. Change it to `!a.get(0).equals(b.get(0)`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko aha you are absolutely right! Can't believe I didn't notice this earlier. I kept experimenting with the difference but never thought to update the if condition with compareTo as well. Thank you so much!

Comment: The `Integer` instances in range `[-128; 127]` are reused, almost like strings. That's why there were no issues with small values like `9` or `12`

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko yeah this is what was tripping me that it was failing for larger values like 10001 when smaller points were correctly ordered. Once again thank you. Could you please post your comment as an answer though? I can accept and close this question.

Comment: On a side note, you could implement this as a `List<Point>` instead of a `List<List<Integer>>`. Using a more meaningful data structure willmake your code more understandable.

Comment: Agree with @Code-Apprentice. With `List<Point> points` your sorting code can be rewritten to IMO more descriptive/readable `points.sort(Comparator.comparing(Point::getX).thenComparing(Point::getY, Comparator.reverseOrder()))` which would also save you from problem you are facing now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am missing something trivial

Method `equals()` should be used for object comparison. Double equals `==` checks whether two references point to the **same object** in memory.

If you change the condition inside the comparator to `!a.get(0).equals(b.get(0))` it will work correctly.

> However, **(10001, -10)** was put before **(10001, -8)**. Even though **-8** is larger than **-10**.

The reason for such behavior is that **JVM** caches all the instances of `Integer` (as well as `Byte`, `Short` and `Long`) in the range **`[-128; 127]`**. I.e. these instances are reused, the result of autoboxing of let's say `int` with a value of `12` will be **always** the same object.

Because small values in your example like `3`, `5`, `12` will be represented by a **single object**, they were compared with `==` without issues. But the result of comparison with `==` for two `Integer` instances with a value of `10001` will be **`false`** because in this case there will be **two distinct objects** in the *heap*.

The approach of caching frequently used objects is called the [**Flyweight design pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern). It's very rarely used in **Java** because this pattern can bring benefits when *tons of identical objects* are being *created and destroyed*. Only in such a case caching these objects will pay off with a significant performance improvement. As far as I know, it's used in game development.

#### Use the power of objects

`Point` must be an object, not a list, as [Code-Apprentice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71363938/17949945) has pointed out in his answer. Use the **power of objects** and don't [overuse collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70993311/how-i-can-access-and-add-value-from-the-list-which-is-nested-in-the-hashmap-and/71113033). It brings several *advantages*:

- class provides you a **structure**, it's easier to organize your code when you are thinking in terms of objects;
- behavior declared inside a class is **reusable** and easier to test;
- with classes, you can use the power of [**polymorphism**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

**Caution:** objects could be also misused, one of the possible indicators of that is when a class doesn't declare any behavior apart from getters and its data is being processed somehow in the code outside this class.

Although the notion of point (*as a geometrical object*) isn't complicated, there are some useful options with regard to methods. For example, you could make instances of the `Point` class to be able to check to whether they are aligned *horizontally* or *vertically*, or whether two points are within a particular *radius*. And `Point` class can implement `Comparable` interface so that points will be able to compare themselves without a `Comparator`.

#### Sorting

With **Java 8** method [**`sort()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator))
was added to the `List` interface. It expects an instance of `Comparator`, and if element of the list implement comparable, and you want them to be sorted according to the natural order `null` can be passed as an argument.

> If the specified comparator is null then all elements in this list must implement the Comparable interface and the elements' natural ordering should be used.

So instead of using utility class `Collections` you can invoke method `sort()` directly on a list of points (assuming that `Point` implements `Comparable<Point>`):

```
points.sort(null); // the same as   points.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Also, you can create multiple custom comparators by utilizing `default` and `static` methods from the `Comparator` interface like [**comparingInt()**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)) and [**thenComparing()**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing(java.util.Comparator)).

(*for more information on how to build comparators with **Java 8** methods take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-comparator-comparing)*)

Answer (score 5):

[@Alexander Ivanchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71363726/1440565) explains very well why you are seeing the behavior you do. One solution to the problem is to use `Integer.compareTo()`:

```
Collections.sort(points, (a, b) -> {
    int xCompare = a[0].compareTo(b[0];
    if (xCompare != 0) {
        return xCompare;
    }
    retirm a[1].compareTo(b[1];
});
```

Beyond this, I suggest creating a `Point` class:

```
class Point {
    public int x;
    public int y;
}
```

Here I use `public` fields to follow the struct pattern. If you want to add getters and setters and other behavior, feel free to do so. Using a class to represent the structure of your data makes the code more understandable and easier to maintain. In fact, you can easily implement `Comparable` on a `Point` or a `Comparator<Point>` class.

Comment: I agree, point has to be definitely represented by a **class**, not a list. And probably it's better to let these points decide how they should be compared. I mean implement `Comparable`

Comment: I kind of consider implementing `Comparable` legacy. I tend to create public static final `Comparator`s (eg `Point.BY_X`) which can be used in pretty much all of the same contexts but are more expressive as to their actual behavior.

Comment: @daniu Yes, creating `Comparator` classes works as well and added that as an option. I think of them as interchangable and am not deeply into Java programming these days to know what best practices are.

Comment: @daniu `Comparable` is not legacy. But it should only be implemented by classes truly having a *natural order*. A point does not have a natural order; there are lots of different strategies someone could pick, so these strategies should indeed be implemented using a `Comparator`.