# Turn a for loop into Recursion

Tags: java, list, algorithm, for-loop, recursion

I have a list of elements that I wanted to print out. The way it is gonna work is that when we read aloud the list `[1,1,1,1,4,4,4]`, we most likely say four `1`s and three `4`s, instead
of uttering each number one by one.

Method `readAloud(List)` should return a `List`.

*For example:*

• `readAloud(List(1,1,1))` should return `List(3,1)`.

• `readAloud(List(-1,2,7))` should return `List(1,-1,1,2,1,7)`.

• `readAloud(List(3,3,8,-10,-10,-10))` should return `List(2,3,1,8,3,-10)`.

• `readAloud(List(3,3,1,1,3,1,1))` should return `List(2,3,2,1,1,3,2,1)`.

As you can see, I have already done it. But how can I turn this code into recursion?

```
        List<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<>();
        int count=1;
        int prev_elt = xs.get(0);
        for(int i=1;i<xs.size();i++){
            if (prev_elt == xs.get(i)){
                count += 1;
            }
            else{
                answer.add(count);
                answer.add(prev_elt);
                prev_elt=xs.get(i);
                count=1;
            }
            if(i == xs.size()-1){
                answer.add(count);
                answer.add(prev_elt);
                prev_elt=xs.get(i);
                count=1;
            }

        }
        return answer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't needed to recurse on this, but you can do this:

```
public static void readAloud (List<Integer> xs, int ind){
    if(ind == xs.size()) return;
    if(ind == 0 || !answer.get(answer.size() - 1).equals(xs.get(ind))) {
        answer.add(1);
        answer.add(xs.get(ind));
    }
    else{
        answer.set(answer.size() - 2, answer.get(answer.size() - 2) + 1);
    }
    readAloud(xs, ind + 1);
}
```

---

Make sure to add ans as a global variable, or pass it in as an argument. This means you have to instantiate it again every time you want to call the method.

Comment: Note - I tested this on IntelliJ, Eclipse, and Repl. Eclipse and IntelIiJ were running different JDKs. The code somehow threw an error on Eclipse, so if you also get an error I'll fix the code.

Comment: The bug that you've encountered has nothing to do with the IDE. Past the following code into the `main()`, run it and see what will be printed: 
        `readAloud(List.of(3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1), 0);
        System.out.println(answer);
        readAloud(List.of(1, 1, 300, 300), 0);
        System.out.println(answer);
        readAloud(List.of(250, 250), 0);
        System.out.println(answer);`

Comment: You are comparing `Integer` objects with `!=`. Which means that you're not checking the values, but whether these two integers are represented with two distinct objects in memory. And that could lead to incorrect results. JVM caches the values that do not exceed the range of `byte`, and therefor two integer objects with value of `3` will be literally represented with the same instance. But with values grater then `127` or less then `-128` your code will break.

Comment: And because you've decided to store the result in a global variable, if the method will be called more than once, list `answer` will contain results of all subsequent calls.

Comment: noted and fixed, thanks, I chose to use a global variable because that's what I usually do but I didn't know it results in worse memory management

Comment: If you don't see any difference between global and local variables, that means that you don't understand the Java memory model. You shouldn't turn a variable into a static field or instance field without any reason. BTW, that **wouldn't work**: *This means you have to instantiate it again every time you want to call the method* - you can't access an instance field from the static method, and the requirement to use to create a new instance isn't a bright idea. Even if you would remove the `static` modifier, the requirement remains to be error-prone and redundant.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to call the method from a static method anyways? If you're calling it from a static method then you can access the static instance right? But I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement this problem recursively, you need to maintain position in the source list (denoted as `pos` in the code below). It will be passed as a parameter and get incremented at each method call.

Every recursive implementation consists of two parts:

- **Base case** - that represents a simple *edge-case* (condition when recursion terminates) for which the outcome is known in advance. In for this task, the **base case** will represent a situation when the source list was discovered completely and position is equal to its size (invalid index).
- **Recursive case** - a part of a solution where recursive calls are made and where the main logic resides.

In the recursive case, we need to determine whether the value at the current position matches the previous value. And if it is the case, increment the resulting count, otherwise add the previous value to the resulting list and add a counter-element (having a value of `1`) for the next value.

My suggestion if to hide actual details of recursive implementation by providing a *convenience method* that requires only one parameter - the source list. And that method will be invoked from the client code.

Also, convenience method treats the edge case with the empty source and simplifies the conditional logic of the recursive method adding the counter-value for the first element (no need to treat the case when previous element doesn't exist because the very recursive call will have the *position parameter* `1`).

***Note:***

- Because `Integer` is an *object*, you should use method `equals()` to compare the values of two instances of `Integer`. By using double equals sign `==` you are checking whether two object references objects point at the *same object* in memory. And the code you've listed "seems to be working" only because you've tested it against the values that JVM caches integers in rage of `byte`, i.e. `[-128,127]` ([*for more information, you might have a look at this question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71363302/java-sorting-list-of-array-vs-sorting-list-of-list/71363726)). It will fail if you would pass let's say `List.of(1, 1, 1, 180, 180)` into it.
- It's highly advisable to make the scope of your variables as *narrow as possible*. The benefit of this basic recommendation is better memory consumption and more transparent code, which easier to debug and maintain. And in this case doesn't make sense to make the resulting list a global variable because you will not able to call the method multiple times (with different input) because the next result will override the previous. `result` list must be limited to the scope of method.

The implementation might look that:

```
public static List<Integer> readAloud(List<Integer> source) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (source.isEmpty()) { // early kill
        return result;
    }
    
    result.add(1); // adding the count for the first element in the source list
    return readAloud(source, result, 1);
}

private static List<Integer> readAloud(List<Integer> source, List<Integer> result, int pos) {
    if (pos == source.size()) { // base case
        result.add(source.get(pos - 1)); // adding the last value from the source list
        return result;
    }
    // recursive case
    int currentInd = result.size() - 1; 
    
    if (source.get(pos - 1).equals(source.get(pos))) {
        result.set(currentInd, result.get(currentInd) + 1); // incrementing the count
    } else {
        result.add(source.get(pos - 1)); // adding the previous value
        result.add(1); // adding the count for a new value
    }
    return readAloud(source, result, pos + 1);
}
```

`main()` - demo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(readAloud(List.of(3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1)));
    System.out.println(readAloud(List.of(1, 1, 1, 180, 180)));
}
```

**Output**

```
[2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2, 180]
```