# How to merge two Maps based on values with Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, java-stream, collectors

I have a `Collection` of `Map`s containing inventory information:

```
 0 
  "subtype" -> "DAIRY"
  "itemNumber" -> "EU999"
  "quantity" -> "60"
 1 
  "subtype" -> "DAIRY"
  "itemNumber" -> "EU999"
  "quantity" -> "1000"
 2 
  "subtype" -> "FRESH"
  "itemNumber" -> "EU999"
  "quantity" -> "800"
 3
  "subtype" -> "FRESH"
  "itemNumber" -> "EU100"
  "quantity" -> "100"
```

I need to condense this list based on the `itemNumber`, while summing the `quantity` and retaining unique `subtypes` in a comma separated string. Meaning, **new** `Map`s would look like this:

```
 0 
  "subtype" -> "DAIRY, FRESH"
  "itemNumber" -> "EU999"
  "quantity" -> "1860"
 1 
  "subtype" -> "FRESH"
  "itemNumber" -> "EU100"
  "quantity" -> "100"
```

I've tried a variations of streams, collectors, groupby etc., and I'm lost.

This is what I have so far:

```
public Collection<Map> mergeInventoryPerItemNumber(Collection<Map> InventoryMap){
        Map condensedInventory = null;
        InventoryMap.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(inv -> new ImmutablePair<>(inv.get("itemNumber"), inv.get("subtype")))), collectingAndThen(toList(), list -> {
            long count = list.stream()
                    .map(list.get(Integer.parseInt("quantity")))
                    .collect(counting());
            String itemNumbers = list.stream()
                    .map(list.get("subtype"))
                    .collect(joining(" , "));
            condensedInventory.put("quantity", count);
            condensedInventory.put("subtype", itemNumbers);

            return condensedInventory;
        });
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach.

- first iterate thru the list of maps.
- for each map, process the keys as required

  - special keys are `itemNumber` and `quantity`
  - `itemNumber` is the joining element for all the values.
  - `quantity` is the value that must be treated as an integer
  - the others are strings and are treated as such (for all other values, if the value already exists in the string of concatenated values, then it is not added again)

Some data

```
List<Map<String, String>> mapList = List.of(
        Map.of("subtype", "DAIRY", "itemNumber", "EU999",
                "quantity", "60"),
        Map.of("subtype", "DAIRY", "itemNumber", "EU999",
                "quantity", "1000"),
        Map.of("subtype", "FRESH", "itemNumber", "EU999",
                "quantity", "800"),
        Map.of("subtype", "FRESH", "itemNumber", "EU100",
                "quantity", "100"));
```

The building process

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = new HashMap<>();

for (Map<String, String> m : mapList) {
    result.compute(m.get("itemNumber"), (k, v) -> {
        for (Entry<String, String> e : m.entrySet()) {
            String key = e.getKey();
            String value = e.getValue();
            if (v == null) {
                v = new HashMap<String, String>();
                v.put(key, value);
            } else {
                if (key.equals("quantity")) {
                    v.compute(key,
                            (kk, vv) -> vv == null ? value :
                                    Integer.toString(Integer
                                            .valueOf(vv)
                                            + Integer.valueOf(
                                                    value)));
                } else {
                    v.compute(key, (kk, vv) -> vv == null ?
                            value : (vv.contains(value) ? vv :
                                    vv + ", " + value));
                }
            }
        }
        return v;
    });
}

List<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<>(result.values());
        
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println(i + " " + list.get(i));
}
```

prints

```
0 {itemNumber=EU100, quantity=100, subtype=FRESH}
1 {itemNumber=EU999, quantity=1860, subtype=DAIRY, FRESH}
```

Note that the map of maps may be more useful that a list of maps. For example, you can retrieve the map for the `itemNumber` by simply specifying the desired key.

```
System.out.println(result.get("EU999"));
```

prints

```
{itemNumber=EU999, quantity=1860, subtype=DAIRY, FRESH}
```

Comment: Accepted as answer as this approach means I don't have to modify how the data is transported between the front end and back end. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing a `Map` here. Every map contains the same keys (*"subtype", "itemNumber", "quantity"*). And they are treated almost like object properties in your code. They are expected to be present in every map and each of them expected to have a specific range of values, although are stored as strings according to your example.

***Side-note:** avoid using row types (like `Map` without generic information in angle brackets `<>`), in such a case all elements inside a collection will be treated as `Object`s.*

`Item` clearly has to be defined as a **class**. By storing these data inside a *map*, you're loosing a possibility to define an **appropriate data type** for each *property*, and also you're not able to **define behaviour** to manipulate with these *properties* (*for more elaborate explanation take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71113033/17949945)*).

```
public class Item {
    private final String itemNumber;
    private Set<Subtype> subtypes;
    private long quantity;

    public Item combine(Item other) {
        Set<Subtype> combinedSubtypes = new HashSet<>(subtypes);
        combinedSubtypes.addAll(other.subtypes);

        return new Item(this.itemNumber,
                        combinedSubtypes,
                        this.quantity + other.quantity);
    }

    // + constructor, getters, hashCode/equals, toString
}
```

Method `combine` represents the logic for merging two items together. By placing it inside this **class**, you could easily reuse and change it when needed.

The best choice for the type of the `subtype` field is an [**enum**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). Because it'll allow to *avoid mistakes* caused by misspelled string values and also **enum**s have an extensive language support (`switch` *expressions* and *statements*, special *data structures* designed especially for *enums*, *enum* could be used with *annotations*).

This custom **enum** can look like this.

```
public enum Subtype {DAIRY, FRESH}
```

With all these changes, the code inside the `mergeInventoryPerItemNumber()` becomes concise and easier to comprehend. `Collectors.groupingBy()` is used to create a map by grouping *items* with the same `itemNumber`. A downstream collector `Collectors.reducing()` is used to combine *items* grouped under the same *key* to a *single object*.

Note that `Collectors.reducing()` produces an `Optional` result. Therefore, `filter(Optional::isPresent)` is used as a precaution to make sure that the result exists and subsequent operation `map(Optional::get)` extracts the **item** from the *optional object*.

```
public static Collection<Item> mergeInventoryPerItemNumber(Collection<Item> inventory) {
    return inventory.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getItemNumber,
                            Collectors.reducing(Item::combine)))
            .values().stream()
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**main()**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Item> inventory =
            List.of(new Item("EU999", Set.of(Subtype.DAIRY), 60),
                    new Item("EU999", Set.of(Subtype.DAIRY), 1000),
                    new Item("EU999", Set.of(Subtype.FRESH), 800),
                    new Item("EU100", Set.of(Subtype.FRESH), 100));

    Collection<Item> combinedItems = mergeInventoryPerItemNumber(inventory);

    combinedItems.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**Output**

```
Item{itemNumber='EU100', subtypes=[FRESH], quantity=100}
Item{itemNumber='EU999', subtypes=[FRESH, DAIRY], quantity=1860}
```

Comment: I have upvoted this, but I accepted another as the answer. I seen a comment of yours that this question is a beginner question and not an enterprise web application - unfortunately this is an enterprise web application that I have inherited. The data is passed between the front end and backend in these undefined maps.
I totally agree these should be defined in a class for easier manipulation. But to implement that now would require changes to the SQL, backend Java app, and front end. So I have accepted the answer that allowed me to stick with returning the Map as is.

Comment: @tripack91 I understand, that's a very compelling reason. Thank you for recognising my idea. And sorry for my incautious conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to do this with a single sweep, but here I have solved it with two passes: one to group like items together, and another over the items in each group to build a representative item (which seems similar in spirit to your code, where you were also attempting to stream elements from groups).

```
   
    public static Collection<Map<String, String>> 
            mergeInventoryPerItemNumber(Collection<Map<String, String>> m){

        return m.stream()
                // returns a map of itemNumber -> list of products with that number
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.get("itemNumber")))
                // for each item number, builds new representative product
                .entrySet().stream().map(e -> Map.of(
                    "itemNumber", e.getKey(), 
                    // ... merging non-duplicate subtypes
                    "subtype", e.getValue().stream()
                        .map(v -> v.get("subtype"))
                        .distinct() // avoid duplicates
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")), 
                    // ... adding up quantities
                    "quantity", ""+e.getValue().stream()
                        .map(v -> Integer.parseInt(v.get("quantity")))
                        .reduce(0, Integer::sum)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String ... args) {
        Collection<Map<String, String>> c = mkMap();
        dump(c);
        dump(mergeInventoryPerItemNumber(c));
    }

    public static Collection<Map<String, String>> mkMap() {
        return List.of(
            Map.of("subtype", "DAIRY", "itemNumber", "EU999", "quantity", "60"),
            Map.of("subtype", "DAIRY", "itemNumber", "EU999", "quantity", "1000"),
            Map.of("subtype", "FRESH", "itemNumber", "EU999", "quantity", "800"),
            Map.of("subtype", "FRESH", "itemNumber", "EU100", "quantity", "100"));
    }

    public static void dump(Collection<Map<String, String>> col) {
        int i = 0;
        for (Map<String, String> m : col) {
            System.out.println(i++);
            for (Map.Entry e : m.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("\t" + e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
```